# Add integer column to datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a field starttime and a duration in minutes in another column.
How do I add the duration to that to get another datetime correctly.
Date_add always tells me "1064 you have an error in your sql syntax".

```
SELECT id, starttime, DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL duration MINUTES) as arrivaltime FROM table
```

Comment: Might seem trivial, but actually I didn't find the answer here. And it took me some to figure out, my error was simple. So if you downvote the question, be as kind as to comment, so I can learn from your view.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I suspect downvoters did so because you did not show the query that generated the syntax error.

Comment: Right. edited. thx!

Comment: @Max: I didn't downvote. But I would suggest you to delete the question as you have already found the answer. You must be aware that deleting this question would revert your deducted reputation as downvote hasn't passed 14 hours yet. It is really ridiculous that people are downvoting without adding their comments.

Comment: I agree, I did find the answer myself. But Stackoverflow is about sharing your epiphanies ... and if I had found it here I would have saved quite some time. Because MYSQL error messages are not too helpful. (1064 ...*rolleyes*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, starttime, DATE_ADD(starttime, interval duration MINUTE) as arrivaltime FROM table
```

My error was it doesn't work with MINUTES 
Maybe that helps others as stupid as myself